# Displaying in the same line with "display()"

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython, sympy

I was using Sympy in Jupyter where I realized I cant display two things in the same line with `display()` command. I know how to do it with `print()` but since I am using Sympy I need to also do it with `display()`. Can someone help me please? Thank you!

The code:

```
display('Value =', smp.Symbol('\Gamma_{\mu\nu}^{\lambda}'))
```

Comment: Related: [IPython Notebook: how to display() multiple objects without newline](/q/17439176/4518341) - This is for strings, but I'm sure there'll be a better solution for SymPy specifically.

Comment: @wjandrea thank you however I was going to display one string and one symbolic value together. Here it is:

`display('Value =', smp.Symbol('\Gamma_{\mu\nu}^{\lambda}'))`

Comment: What if you made the string symbolic too? `display(smp.Eq(smp.Symbol('Value'), smp.Symbol(...)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your problem, you may use "Eq":

```
   value, gm, lam = symbols('Value, Gamma_mu_nu ,lambda')
   Eq(value,gm**lam)
```

[image: Value=gamma_mu_nu^lambda latex display]